# Twitter Bootstrap Button-how to link to another page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, routes

I'm trying to link one of the buttons using the  tag (the button comes from Twitter bootstrap) i.e. class of the a tag is equal to the button and then the href is the link where it should redirect to (don't have the code because it's not displaying properly).

The file that this line of code exists is in app/views/candidates/show, but I want to link it to app/views/donations/index.html.erb. I keep getting a routing error, not sure why (I also have controllers set up for donations and candidates, and have a model association between candidates and donations i.e. a candidate has many donations, and have them linked via a donation_id. Not sure what else I need to do in order to get the routing to work).

Here is the rake routes print out:

```
candidates_show GET    /candidates/show(.:format)     candidates#show
candidates_new GET    /candidates/new(.:format)      candidates#new
donations_index GET    /donations/index(.:format)     donations#index
home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)          home#index
import_candidates POST   /candidates/import(.:format)   candidates#import
candidates GET    /candidates(.:format)          candidates#index
POST   /candidates(.:format)          candidates#create
new_candidate GET    /candidates/new(.:format)      candidates#new
edit_candidate GET    /candidates/:id/edit(.:format) candidates#edit
candidate GET    /candidates/:id(.:format)      candidates#show
PUT    /candidates/:id(.:format)      candidates#update
DELETE /candidates/:id(.:format)      candidates#destroy
root        /                              home#index
```

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. Is your problem really related with Twitter Bootstrap? Can you show some code with how the two views are linked (the controller code and code from the view that displays the links)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%= link_to("donations", donations_index_path, class: "btn") %>
```

Also consider specifying donations as a resource like

```
resources :donations
```

which will give you a simpler `donations_path` helper for

```
donations GET /donations(.:format) donations#index
```